# How should I define a line in an event's programme?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm currently struggling with defining parts of an event programme in a database structure.

In Norwegian it's called "programpost", which makes "program post" feel natural. But there is nothing on the internet as far as I can tell to validate this term. Google Translate suggests "program record", but I don't think this is a commonly used term. I have also considered "programme entry".

Is there any common term for this information? If the programme was to be presented as a spreadsheet, each row would represent for example a contest, or a presentation or similar things that people would do at the event, ordered by time.

Does anyone know, or have ideas for which terms might work?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. Request for single-term definitions are off-topic for us, but acceptable on English, and I *think* your post is written to their specs. I will ask the mods to migrate.

Comment: I think OP is asking about a program ***track***.  A series of related non-overlapping events/sessions that are designed to be followed sequentially by an event attendee.

Comment: @Jim That's not quite what I meant, but I learned a new term! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The catchall term for these things in English is 'item'.

> The program has 12 items.

[Item](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/item) (MW, noun definitions 2-4)

> a distinct part in an enumeration, account, or series; article
>
> an object of attention, concern, or interest
>
> a separate piece of news or information

In programming, you may want to use the term 'element' instead.

> Create a many-to-one relationship between program_elements and programs.

[Element](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/element) (MW, definition 2)

> a constituent part